# Embedding words inside text at specific index

Tags: java, regex

I have a text and I want to include a word in the text at specific index. I managed to find the index of the text where I need to include the new word. However, I can not find a way to use that index for the embedding process. I tried to use replace function as follows:

```
newSentence = oldSentence.replace(oldWord, (oldWord+" "+newWord));
```

The problem is that this method replaces all occurrences of the oldWord while I want only words at specific index to be changed.

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "at a specific index"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StringBuilder#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29). It can replace a portion of a given `String` like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldSentence);
sb.replace(wordPos, newWord.length()-1, newWord);
newSentence = sb.toString();
```

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public StringBuilder replace(int start,
                    int end,
                    String str)
```

> Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String. The substring begins at the specified start and extends to the character at index end - 1 or to the end of the sequence if no such character exists. First the characters in the substring are removed and then the specified String is inserted at start. (This sequence will be lengthened to accommodate the specified String if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

In Java you cannot change the contents of a String.

You must build a new one by extracting the text before the word you want to replace, and the text after the word, and concatenating all three (before, word, after) in a new String.  Look at the `StringBuilder` library class.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append(oldSentence.substring(0,wordPos));
buf.append(newWord);
buf.append(oldSentence.substring(wordPos+oldWordLength));
```

Comment: Another option (same result): `buf = new StringBuilder(oldSentence).insert(wordPos, newWord);`

Answer (score 1):

```
oldWord.substring(0, index) + embeddedText + oldWord.substring(index);
```

This is assuming that your index value is the nth character after which you want to embed your text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceFirst()`, but to be safe you should turn your text into a regex quoted string, in case the "word" contains any sprcial regex characters like a dot:

```
newSentence = oldSentence.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(oldWord), oldWord+" "+newWord);
```

Or slightly more "regexy", turn the wird into a look-behind:

```
newSentence = oldSentence.replaceFirst("(?<="Pattern.quote(oldWord)+")", " "+newWord);
```